# Plus.Builder.build() throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MAJOR_VERSION

Tags: java, google-plus

Using the libs from the [gplus java quickstart](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/) I get a nosuchfielderror whenever I try to create an instance of the plus service with the following code:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new UrlFetchTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build()
            .setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);
    Plus service = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MAJOR_VERSION
    at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus.(Plus.java:48)
    at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus$Builder.build(Plus.java:2133)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the quickstart you mention contains in its 'libs' folder two different versions of the API

1. The original used for the quickstart (1.13.2-beta)
2. A version that uses jetty for better compatibility (1.17.0-rc)

Unfortunately, your application seems to favor the 1.17 version of `google-api-services-plus`, while it uses the 1.13 version of `google-api-client`. In that version there is a file `GoogleUtils.java` that doesn't feature the `MAJOR_VERSION` field.

The open question is: how to best solve this.

I'd try to just remove all the 1.13.2-beta (and 1.13.1-beta) libs from the `libs` folder, and see how far that brings you. Ideally the quickstart would be fixed by the owner.

Comment: Using only the 1.17.0-rc libs resolves the NoSuchFieldError but when I execute the following code a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPMethod is thrown

Plus.Activities.Search req = service.activities().search(q);

ActivityFeed feed = req.execute();

Comment: `HTTPMethod` is a class in the Appengine SDK; I don't think it is in one of the jars in the `lib` folder,.. Although the tutorial doesn't mention it, maybe you should download ([here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java)) and install the SDK. I must admit that we're getting a bit out of my expertise here..

Comment: This is correct.  The GitHub repo has been updated to remove the extra client library jars from the Java quick-start app.

Comment: So its not possible to use these libraries in a console app on my own pc?